# Add a new vector to a nested list

Tags: r, purrr

I'm just learning to work with lists in R, and I have gotten pretty close to what I want to do. I'm raising my hand for a little push in the right direction:

```
my_data <- 
  data.frame(group = c(sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 20, replace = TRUE)), 
                      x = runif(100, 0, 10)) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(number = sample(3:7, 3))
```

## **What I'd like to do:**

Simple, really. I want to add a new vector to the nested list ("data") containing the corresponding value from the "number" vector. So, for example, the first 5 rows of the first element in the list would look something like this:

```
head(my_data$data[[1]],5) %>% mutate(y=4)
```

But I don't know how to do this! (Obviously I hard-coded the above example.)

## **I've tried:**

Lots of permutations of unlist, unnest, map, pluck. I didn't record all the stuff I've tried.

Comment: In Base R, you could use `Map`, `my_data$data <- Map(cbind, my_data$data, y = my_data$number)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you try to create a function which adds the new column:

```
require(tidyverse)

my_data <- my_data %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, function(x) { 
    x %>% 
      mutate(y = 4)
    }))
```

Result:

```
my_data$data[1]
[[1]]
# A tibble: 30 x 2
        x     y
    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 5.97       4
 2 7.44       4
 3 9.96       4
 4 9.98       4
 5 0.0933     4
 6 1.45       4
 7 9.78       4
 8 6.88       4
 9 5.10       4
10 6.68       4
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was expecting a function would do the trick best, and this helps! Actually, the real question was just a bit more complicated: the value I wanted to supply was a different vector in the parent data frame. I ended up solving it a different way, but your way is better.

Comment: You're welcome and glad I could help :). Don't forget that you can always just `nest` the variables that you want and leave variables out of the nesting for your use (`mtcars %>% 
  nest(-cyl, -vs)`, cyl and vs will not be nested).

Comment: that was actually part of my solution. i wanted to assign id numbers to members of a category. So I nested by category, assigned row numbers with `rowname_to_column`, and then I wanted to assign those row numbers to all the nested items. That was the original problem where I got stuck. I solved it rather brutishly (I'm new at this). :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `purrr::map2` in the case you have two vectors to iterate over

```
library(tidyverse)
my_data <- my_data %>% mutate(data_mod=map2(data,number,cbind))
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked, mostly. 

Two follow-ups. 1) I get this warning: "In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character). 2) For each element in the list, I also get this warning: "In bind_rows_(x, .id) : binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector". 

Finally, is there a way to name the new vector in data_mod?

Comment: @Steve Try `my_data %>% mutate(data_mod=map2(data,number,data.frame,stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% map(setNames,nm=c('x','y')))`

Comment: I'm going to try this when I get a chance, because I think I can learn something from it. Please see my comments above. Thanks!